# Is a 'pace' the same as a 'step'?

Tags: word-choice

In the following sentence can I use either of the two? step/pace and until/til

> It took exactly twenty-five paces(steps) from the office door
>   until(till) her desk.

What sounds more natural to the native ear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *pace* usually means the stride one ordinarily takes in unimpeded walking: roughly thirty inches, or three-quarters of a meter.

> But the ancient Roman military *passus*, usually translated 'pace', was two strides: in marching, the distance between successive strikes of the same heel. The English 'mile' of just over 5,000 feet derives from the Roman *mille* of one thousand paces.

A *step* has a broader range: it may be a step up or down, as well as a step on level ground, and even on level ground the particular footing—mud, or snow, or ice, or vegetation—may enforce steps smaller than a full stride.

Accordingly, *pace* is more usual for approximate measurements.

In your example, however, *pace* will be appropriate only if the path from the door to the desk is unimpeded—for instance, down an aisle between desks or cubicles. If there are turns or obstacles, *step* may be all that is enumberable.

Whichever unit of measure you use, the ordinary construction is *so many X from A **to** B*, not *until* or *till*. *Until* and *till* mark endpoints in time, and even there are used mostly for time as experienced rather than measured.

> He worked *until* four o'clock, *BUT*
>   He works from nine **to** five.

Comment: The other reason I prefer _pace_ to _step_ in this context is the other meanings of the word _step_, for example: _It was twenty-five steps from raw ingredients to finished product_. Such additional meanings don't prevent the word _step_ from being used, of course, but it can make _pace_ a better option.

Comment: @J.R. true; although *pace*, too, has other meanings: "Work proceeded at a brisk *pace*", or "Jane fell behind early, because she was *pacing* herself; eventually she overtook the leaders".

Comment: True enough! But when I hear the expression "10 steps," I often initially think of a 10-step program, or 10-step procedure, rather than 10 strides across the floor. On the other hand, if I hear "10 paces," I don't normally associate that with the pace of my work.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you want to specify an exact number of steps, then *paces* sounds more natural:

> My sofa is ten paces from the fridge
>
> My sofa is ten steps from the fridge (or My sofa is ten footsteps from the fridge).

In context however, it sounds like *twenty-five paces* is being as a rough estimate of length, which is why it sounds a little forced. A native would much more likely use an alternative unit of length:

> It is twenty-five **feet** from the office door to her desk.

Comment: A native (at least this native) would only use that unit of length if a tape measure was used to obtain the measurement. I agree with you, though, "exactly twenty-five paces" sounds a little odd, because _paces_ is a rough unit of measurement, so it doesn't go well with the word "exactly". I'd suggest: "It was twenty-five paces from the office door to her desk," or maybe, "It was an even twenty-five paces from the office door to her desk."

Comment: @J.R. Does 'an even xyz' mean 'around/roughly'?

Comment: @Soulz: :^) I wondered if that might prompt another question. "Even" can be used to say that something came out to a nice round number. If I buy six items at the grocery store, at the total comes out to $9.00, I might say, "Wow, that's an even nine dollars," meaning it wasn't $9.02, or $8.97. In this example, I wouldn't say "an even 22 steps" or "an even 26 steps", but I might use _even_ when the number happens to be a multiple of 10 or 25. So, although the measurement in paces is a rough estimate of length, the number of paces it happens to be is a nice "even" number (i.e., a multiple of 25).